# Error in importing UNet with Sementation models in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, semantic-segmentation

I'm fairly new to machine learning.

I was trying to do some semantic segmentation using Segmentation models on Google colab.

I just installed Segmentations models with the line.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
```

then, at the "model=sm.Unet(~~" line from the block. I got the error code.

```
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)


# define model
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss', metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score, 'mse'])

print(model.summary())
```

and this is the error code.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/classification_models/weights.py in load_model_weights(model, model_name, dataset, classes, include_top, **kwargs)
     23                              ' as true, `classes` should be {}'.format(weights['classes']))
     24 
---> 25         weights_path = keras_utils.get_file(
     26             weights['name'],
     27             weights['url'],

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file'
```

can someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: which version of keras/tensorflow are you using? it is probably some libraries versions mismatch

Comment: on the colab it says 2.5.0